# Link Duplicity and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am running Apache 2.2.11

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

**The Problem:**
`http://localhost/index` gives me the Homepage(index.php) properly, but I can also access the same page through the following urls.

```
http://localhost/index/
http://localhost/index/blahblah
http://localhost/index/blahblah/blah/blah/blah
http://localhost/index.php/
http://localhost/index.php/blahblah/
http://localhost/index.php/blahblah/blah/blah
```

I want to ensure that only localhost/index will open localhost/index.php, anything other than localhost/index (even localhost/index.php) should return a 404.

I guess I will have to add another `RewriteCond` for catching all else but existing Request_Filename.php files. **How do I get a 404 for all else but localhost/index?**

(This question is on SO too with a bounty, but I guess serverfault might be a better place for it.)
**Update**
What does the .htaccess do? The aim of the htaccess files is to enable cleaner urls like localhost/index instead of localhost/index.php
 more explanation can be found at the [source of this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745680/htaccess-rewrite-causes-500-error-instead-of-404/1750696#1750696)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the change in scope of the question, I'm going to take another crack at answering it...

> What does the .htaccess do?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

1. Match if the requested URI is not a
   valid file.
2. Match if the requested URI is not a
   valid directory.
3. Match if the requested URI plus "any
   single character" plus "php" **is**
   a valid PHP file (note that this
   will match "index-php" just as well
   as "index.php" - you should escape
   the period character if you want a
   literal match).
4. Pass the request through to
   "whatever the request string was"
   (`^(.*)$`) plus ".php" - append the
   query string (`[QSA]`) and stop
   processing mod_rewrite directives
   after this rule (`[L]`).

There are some serious problems with these rules - for example, if you create a directory named "index", users requesting "domain.com/index" will get the directory, not your index.php file.

Given your stated intent:

> I want to ensure that only
>   localhost/index will open
>   localhost/index.php, anything other
>   than localhost/index (even
>   localhost/index.php) should return a
>   404.

... I would recommend the following implementation:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index$
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,QSA]
```

**index.php**

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/index' ) {
  header("Status: 404 Not Found");
  require( '404.html' );
  die();
}
```

**Update:**

> How can I do the same thing without
>   having a script at index.php?

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way that this can be done without invoking a kludge because any rule which applies to /index.php will be triggered when /index is passed on to /index.php

Here's the inelegant kludge:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?rw=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rw=1 [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

(Anyone can access "/index.php?rw=1" now - it's not as elegant as the script edit)

Comment: +1 if i had the rep. thanks for the detailed answer. How can I do the same thing without having a script at index.php?